# swift change label on uitableviewcell background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have UItablview with custom cell i need to change a label background colour when select this row, but the label colour is repeated when scroll down

[image]

Comment: Could you please show use what you have tried ? Please, take some time to read this: [ask]

Comment: You are reusing the cell, that is the reason of changed label's background color, you need to show the cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

Comment: the cell is selected in the custom cell class so it has colour when i select + - button how can i use cellForRowAtIndexPath to update the colour

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass your Cell like this (and cellForRow then will not be responsible for updating the color, only for setting default color).

```
class YourTableViewCellClass: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if(selected) {

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //or what you want as your cell bg color
        self.yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green //or what you want

    } else {

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //or what you want as your cell bg color
        self.yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //or what you want
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is, you put code in didSelectRow method of tableview to change the color, but it shows previous color while scrolling.

So,you need to set condition in cellForRow method also e.g.

```
if(condition)
{
lbl.textcolor = x
}
else
{
lbl.textcolor = y
}
```